# Digital signal calibration

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

while True:
    val = 17
    GPIO.setup(val,GPIO.IN)
    val1 = val * 1200000/255
    print val1

GPIO.cleanup()
```

A serial monitor (via Arduino) shows values in range 0-255 as sensor works, but raspberry don't take that values as val and solve for val1.
all I see is,taking val as 17 and print 80000 constantly.

Answer (score 1):

The pi GPIOs are digital, meaning at any given point they either have a value of 0 or 1.  Since they can be read at a high frequency (the impediment here in general WRT the GPIOs is actually the nature of a multi-tasking OS, but for the ones with hardware timing where that issue is easily handled by a protocol interface such as UART, the frequency is at least 8 Mhz), this can translate into a stream of binary data.

But simply reading the value of a pin at any given point is still always going to return either 0 or 1.  That doesn't explain your answer because as far as I can tell (I'm actually not a python user, but I am certain in this case) you aren't even doing that.  Let's take a close look:

```
val = 17
```

Okay, we have an (integer) variable with a value of 17.  Presumably this is the GPIO pin number you want to use, because that's how it is then applied.  But next:

```
val1 = val * 1200000/255
print val1
```

**This isn't reading the pin.**  This is equivalent to:

```
val1 = 17 * 12000000/255
```

And guess what that *always* is?

Again, I'm not a python user so I can't tell you the correct way to read a pin<sup>1</sup> but that's your error.

---

<sup>1. I am also positive that is a question which does not need asking here or anywhere else as it *must* be clear from a glance at the documentation, and there must be thousands of examples besides online by now.  If you want to write code, you do have to be able to *read documentation and examples* or it will take you forever to get nowhere.</sup>

Comment: yes, I do know that is the problem, but I want to know how to correct it. here val always 17 !! it should be variable value as it read GPIO. still I'm LOST!!

Comment: No it shouldn't "be variable value as it read GPIO".  The reason you're lost is because *you have not bothered to read the documentation for `RPi.GPIO` or looked at any examples of how to use it*.  If you have, **look again** because I promise what they are doing is not what you are doing.

Comment: I recognize that English isn't your first language and that this unfortunately is a bit of an obstacle with programming, because the programming languages are anglo-centric as is their primary documentation.  I can't do anything about that and I believe it's simply an accepted fact in a lot of technical and engineering fields: The universal language is English.  So you may have to slow down, focus, etc.  If you want to do this you don't have a choice about learning that way.   Good luck and remember to get up and walk around occasionally, it may help to clear the patterns in your mind.

Comment: RPi.GPIO was good tip. others lol.

Comment: ;) Please don't tell me that means English is your first language >_<  *("Kids these days...")*

Comment: no bother , done with SPI !!

Comment: Yes sensors are generally SPI or I2C based, not one wire.  The more (relevant) information you include in your question the quicker and easier it is to get an easy answer ;\

Comment: no dear, my sensor is analog !

Comment: Ah well then you need something in the middle.  I did consider that since the Arduino has analog inputs where the Pi does not, but again, you need to be clear and explicit if you want to skip straight to the juicy bits.